# How to change a script in R to UTF-8?

Tags: r, encoding

I created my R Markdown script with accents in my original language, but I don't think I saved with UTF-8 encoding. When I opened it in another version of RStudio, the encoding was distorted ... I saved the file as UTF-8 but the text was not corrected, is there any way to correct the text for UTF-8?

Comment: Try File\Reopen with encoding  and choose the appropriate encoding

Comment: Thank you. I found this option, but when I reopened in UTF-8 it didn't correct my accents. Maybe the coding is not exactly that ...

Comment: I have had issues with this as well. The way I solved it was trial and error with different coding until it worked (e.g. UTF-16, UTF-32)

Comment: I only managed to solve this link, pasting all my script and selecting "UTF8 decode": https://cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/utf8_encode